# Have one Java web app talk to another in a Tomcat container

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, tcp

I have two web apps (packaged as WARs) which I deploy to Tomcat 7. Both are simple Java apps.

In **a very simple way** I'd like one webapp to to pass simple String variables to the other app whenever it wants to.

So for example App A says to App B "Here's a string, here's another one, and another..." and so forth.

Currently it's looking like RMI might be a nice way to go - App B could expose a method `passMeAString(String string)` and App A could call it over `TCP` and pass the strings. This could also be good as there is no TCP access externally so the outside world wouldn't be able to invoke the method.

**Is this a good way to go? Is there an easier way?** Of course exposing a public interface (out to the world world) is not an option.

Also, just to help me out, examples would be really helpful.

Comment: just use simple http  with parameters

Comment: "Is this a good way to go? Is there an easier way?" I consider this suboptimal because it imposes dependencies between the two apps and you'd reinvent the wheel somehow. Maybe you should consider using (locally accessible) REST-APIs or a MessageQueue (of which there are plenty implementations).

Comment: With RMI you also expose an interface, I'm not sure I understand what's wrong with a pubic interface for you, could you clarify?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I guess there is confusion about what "public" is. As I read it, OP does not want that functionality be accessible from "the world" but only between the two apps on the same tomcat. So IMHO, "privacy" has to be implemented on another level as Application. The otherwise public interface has to be "hidden" from the outside world on container-level.

Comment: @Fildor Exactly what I meant, thanks for clarifying on my behalf

Answer (score 0):

1. If your services are not going to be used by the third party and you are expecting performance then you can go ahead with RMI (Java<->Java communication and serialization are handy.)
2. If you are considering your services needs to be talk to someother party then you have to expose it as REST service and call it using basic Apache Http client (you can use Aysync / sync ).